# Unity spent half an hour importing assets after merging Git branches

Tags: git, unity-game-engine

I have `master` and `develop` Git branches in my Unity project.  While working on my `develop` branch, I added a lot of sprites.  Then I closed the Unity editor, switched to `master`, and merged `develop` into it.  Then I switched back to `develop` and opened Unity.  Upon starting, Unity took half an hour to import all of my assets before it opened.  I've got a couple questions:

1. Is the reason that Unity had to reimport all of these asset files because the file dates changed when I switched to `master` (which did not originally have these files in it) and then switched back to `develop`?
2. Is this a common problem or an I doing something incorrectly which is causing this to happen?
3. Is it normal practice to exclude images from Unity Git repositories?

Comment: yikes! , 1. not sure could be dates changed it or pulled projects setting from master , 2. not sure about this specifically but git being a time sink with unity projects is pretty common  3. its up to you, if its under the 100mb file limit its possible but situations like yours where images cause a time sink make it discretionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the reason that Unity had to reimport all of these asset files
>   because the file dates changed when I switched to master (which did
>   not originally have these files in it) and then switched back to
>   develop?

As you explained it on top you switched from develop (sprites) to master (no sprites) then merged develop (sprites) into master (no sprites). So you went from a lot of sprites to not and then back to a lot of sprites again. So from the editor's perspective, you added a bunch of sprites, removed them and then readded them at which point unity has to go through the 'new' files and reimport them.

> Is this a common problem or an I doing something incorrectly which is
>   causing this to happen?

I wouldn't call this a problem per se, its normal operating procedure (Although i get what you're saying). Half an hour seems a bit long though, although that could depend on a lot of things and without knowing anything about your environment (hardware etc) or setup (amount of sprites added where etc) its hard to say whether half an hour 'is normal'.

A simple google search turned up some improvements to be made to improve the load times, for example to not compress the images;

[image]

I wouldn't bother with this though since you likely won't be switching branches like this a lot buts its a nice setting if you do anyways.

> Is it normal practice to exclude images from Unity Git repositories?

Depends on your design. If you need the 'images' (this seems very broad) you should definitely add them to version control. Although i've also seen situations (in none unity3d apps) where the images where downloaded from a remote server. This depends on your requirements but generally speaking i'd say yes.

There's also Git lfs (git large file storage) btw but i haven't used it; https://git-lfs.github.com/

Comment: Very thorough response.  Thank you.  I've looked into LFS a bit, and from my understanding that only affects how the files are stored and transferred to GitHub, so I think I'd still have this same problem when I add/update my image assets.  I could be wrong though.

Comment: @BenRubin yes indeed it was just something that popped in my mind, since you asked about excluding the images from your project. Also quick question now that i think of it, do you `.gitignore` your `.meta` files or not?

Comment: @sommen I'm using the default `.gitignore` Unity file, which doesn't ignore `.meta` files.

Comment: ah okay thats good. I still feel like half an hour is a lot but i could not speculate as to why that is.